# Interpolating missing data in a dataframe with R

Tags: r, dplyr, interpolation, lag

I have a dataframe which is similar to the one below:

```
Country Ccode Year Happiness Power   
1  France    FR 2000      1000  1000  
2  France    FR 2001        NA    NA
3  France    FR 2002        NA    NA
4  France    FR 2003      1600  2200
5  France    FR 2004        NA    NA
6      UK    UK 2000      1000  1000  
7      UK    UK 2001        NA    NA
8      UK    UK 2002      1000  1000  
9      UK    UK 2003      1000  1000
10     UK    UK 2004      1000  1000
```

I have previously used the following code to get the differences:

```
df <- df %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%  #sort data
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(d = . - lag(.)))
```

I would like expand on this code by calculating the difference between the data points of `Happiness` and `Power`, divide it by the difference in years between the data points and calculate the values to replace the NA's with, resulting in the following output.

```
Country Ccode Year Happiness Power   
1  France    FR 2000      1000  1000  
2  France    FR 2001      1200  1400    
3  France    FR 2002      1400  1800
4  France    FR 2003      1600  2200
5  France    FR 2004        NA    NA
6      UK    UK 2000      1000  1000  
7      UK    UK 2001        0      0
8      UK    UK 2002      1000  1000  
9      UK    UK 2003      1000  1000
10     UK    UK 2004      1000  1000
```

What would be an efficient way of carrying out this task?

EDIT: Please note that also `France 2004` is `NA`. The extend function does seem to properly deal with such a situation.

EDIT 2: Adding the group_by(country) seems to mess things up for unknown reasons:It seems that the code is trying to convert a `character` to a `numeric`, although I do not really understand why. When I convert the column to `character`, the error becomes an evaluation error. Any suggestions?

```
> TRcomplete<-TRcomplete%>%
+     group_by(country) %>%
+     mutate_at(70:73,~na.fill(.x,"extend"))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `F116.s` can't be converted from character to numeric
> TRcomplete$F116.s <- as.numeric(TRcomplete$F116.s)
> TRcomplete<-TRcomplete%>%
+     group_by(country) %>%
+     mutate_at(70:73,~na.fill(.x,"extend"))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `F116.s` can't be converted from character to numeric
> TRcomplete$F116.s <- as.numeric(as.character(TRcomplete$F116.s))
> TRcomplete<-TRcomplete%>%
+     group_by(country) %>%
+     mutate_at(70:73,~na.fill(.x,"extend"))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `F116.s` can't be converted from character to numeric
> TRcomplete$F116.s <- as.character(TRcomplete$F116.s))
Error: unexpected ')' in "TRcomplete$F116.s <- as.character(TRcomplete$F116.s))"
> TRcomplete$F116.s <- as.character(TRcomplete$F116.s)
> str(TRcomplete$F116.s)
 chr [1:6984] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> TRcomplete<-TRcomplete%>%
+     group_by(country) %>%
+     mutate_at(70:73,~na.fill(.x,"extend"))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: need at least two non-NA values to interpolate.
```

Comment: You sure year 2003 for France is 1400? since 2001 to 2003 is 2 year and 2003 to 2004 is 1 one year only

Comment: I made a mistake in the example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `na.fill` with `fill="extend"` from the `zoo` library

```
rapply(df, zoo::na.fill,"integer",fill="extend",how="replace")
  Country Ccode Year Happiness Power
1  France    FR 2000      1000  1000
2  France    FR 2001      1200  1400
3  France    FR 2003      1400  1800
4  France    FR 2004      1600  2200
5      UK    UK 2000      1000  1000
6      UK    UK 2001      1000  1000
7      UK    UK 2003      1000  1000
8      UK    UK 2004      1000  1000
```

## EDIT:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
df%>%
  group_by(Country)%>%
  mutate_at(4:5,~na.fill(.x,"extend"))

  Country Ccode Year Happiness Power
1  France    FR 2000      1000  1000
2  France    FR 2001      1200  1400
3  France    FR 2003      1400  1800
4  France    FR 2004      1600  2200
5      UK    UK 2000      1000  1000
6      UK    UK 2001      1000  1000
7      UK    UK 2003      1000  1000
8      UK    UK 2004      1000  1000
```

If all the elements in the group are `NA` then:

```
df%>% 
  group_by(Country)%>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric,~if(all(is.na(.x))) NA else na.fill(.x,"extend"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That library makes it a lot easier. Would it be possible to make the solution conditional on whether the country is still the same and/or the year is still the next one?. The code currently also extends when the first and last row of a country are NA, which is something I should prevent at all cost.

Comment: @TomKisters Just group by country

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was trying to run the code again with the addition, but this time it's giving me a weird error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column can't be converted from character to numeric`

Comment: @TomKisters Just run the specified columns. ie only the numeric columns. That is column four and column five. you can use `df%>% group_by(Country)%>% mutate_if(is.numeric,~na.fill(.x,"extend"))`

Comment: Thank you so much for the follow up. I'll mess with it a bit tomorrow. The weird thing is that the error is referring to a numerical column (in addition, like I said, the code (without the group by country) ran perfectly the first time. I&#39;m going to look at it with a fresh head in the morning. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have not really been able to figure out what is going wrong. I have added some console output.